# parameterize examples in cucumber queries

Tags: automated-tests, cucumber, cucumber-java

I am new to Cucumber. I have a requirement to use variables instead of actual values in a feature file example. Actual values are to be populated  in a separate property file.
Sample feature file:

```
    @tag
    Feature: Add an element to stack
      The user pushes an element. It gets added to stack
      @tag1
      Scenario: Push element to empty stack
        Given Stack is empty
        When User pushes an element
        Then stack should have only one element

      @tag2
      Scenario Outline: Push element to stack
        Given Stack has {initial} elements
        When User adds {new} element
        Then Length of stack increases to {new_size}
        | initial       | new       | new_size       |
        |           1   |       2   |               2|
        |           5   |       9   |               6|
        |           0   |       3   |               1|
```

The output example should be like:

```
    | initial       | new       | new_size       |
    |   {val1_1}    |{val1_2}   |        {val1_3}|
    |   {val2_1}    |{val2_2}   |        {val2_3}|
```

I have used "{}" instead of "<>" as am not able to print elements inside <> in pre-formatted code

Answer (score 1):

Use scenario outlines with examples. Its will solve you data input based queries. For example,

```
 @tag2
 Scenario Outline: Push element to stack
  Given Stack has <initial> elements
  When User adds <new> element
  Then Length of stack increases to <new_size>
  Examples:
  | initial | new | new_size |
  | 1       | 2   | 2        |
  | 5       | 9   | 6        |
  | 0       | 3   | 1        |
```

And your step definition would be like this,

```
        Given("^Stack has (.*) elements$", (String initial) -> {
        // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
        throw new PendingException();
    });
```

Similarly do for the other query parameters like (name, new_size).

Comment: my requirement is to use variables in examples section of a scenario outline and read them from a properties file.

Comment: In your step definition class, read the property file and make it to use for your scenario outline examples. Java has a property reader make use of it, read it in key-value pair.